# How to locally share photos on a Mac

Tags: photos, high-sierra

I have two user accounts on my Mac, and I need the photo library (full of Photos) on the secondary account to be shared with the primary account. I can't use iCloud as the library exceeds 5GB and I can't buy more storage. Solution?

Answer (score 1):

Apple documents that every release of their photo app if things change.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201517

Pretty easy to put the library outside the home folder of the users and share.

Comment: Now, some people run into issues if the steps are not done right or you don’t like the limitations with this and details that need to be managed. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225915/sharing-a-photos-library-across-multiple-accounts?

Answer (score 1):

In the end I transferred the .photolibrary folder to the Users/Shared folder and pointed photos to that directory (open photos while holding option (alt)).

Answer (score -1):

You could copy the photo library onto a thumb drive and transfer that way.

In Finder, go to your Pictures folder and find the file named “Photo Library”. Copy that onto a thumb drive, sign in to your other user account, paste it into the Pictures folder, then double click to open it.